# How can I change the user system login name in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

When I create a new JavaScript file in WebStorm then following pattern is inserted:

```js
/**
 * Created by ${USER} on ${DATE}.
 */
```

How can I change the value of the `${USER}` variable?

Comment: It's in the settings. Can't recall where off the top of my head, but I've seen it before while messing around.

Answer (score 0):

It's coming from your login name, you need to just set it manually:

```
#set( $MyName = "Your Name" )
/**
 * Created by $MyName on ${DATE}.
 */
```